# node js Aggregate with geonear returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> I am getting undefined when using the aggregate in nodejs, for find() query it's working. the same geoNear query in python its working fine, please help me

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017',(err,client) => {
    if(err){
        console.log('db connection failed');
    } else  {
        var db = client.db('DB_NAME');
        db.collection('COLLECTION',(err, collectionname) => {
            if(err){
                console.log('unable to connect to collecion');
            } else {
                collectionname.aggregate([
                    { 
                        "$geoNear": {
                            "near": 
                                 {"type": "Point","coordinates":[77.102490,28.704059]},
                              "distanceField": "distancefromcust",
                              "direction": "direction",
                              "maxDistance":  1000,
                              "spherical": "true",
                              "num":100000
                         }
                    },
                    {"$group":
                      {
                      "_id":
                          {
                              "operator":"$operator",
                              "direction":"$direction"
                          },
                          "speed":{"$push":"$speed"},
                          "samples":{"$push":"$samples"},
                          "distance":{"$push":"$distancefromcust"},
                      }
                  }
                ],(err, item) => {
                    console.log(item.length);
                    client.close();
                });
            }

        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(item.length)
```

Maybe callback not return array.
You should check the value type.

Comment: i am getting object type. if i print object it giving "AggregationCursor"

Answer (score 0):

```
    router.get('/locationgeoNear', function(req,res,next){
  Model.aggregate([
       {
           $geoNear: {
               near: {type: 'point', coordinates: [parseFloat(req.query.lat), parseFloat(req.query.lng)] },
               "distanceField": "100000",
               "maxDistance": 100,
               "spherical": true
           }
       }
   ],function(err, collection, next){
       res.send(collection);
   });
});
```

1. I have been working on getting location data from a really long time. With the latest updates i couldn't find other ways. This one is the best.
2. Start with big max distance if you are not getting the result.
3. Utilizes mongoose, express, node and mongoDB all.